# How to auto update a cell to the current date if another cell´s value got changed

Tags: excel

I would like to do the following: Whenever anything in cell A2, A3, A4 is changed, the corresponding date in cell B2, B3, B4 should be updated to the current date. If nothing is done in A2, A3, A4, the dates in B2, B3, B4 should not be updated.

Any ideas how to accomplish that?

For reference pls. see the screenshot 
[image]

Comment: I found a way to do it.
If one creates a VBA-Project with this code, it works:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:A4")) _
Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

The only problem is, that if I want to "undo" any change of value in p.e. A3, the Strg+Z combination does not work, neither the undo function in the menu-bar.

Any inputs in the cells A2,A3,A4 cannot be undone.

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use VBA and the worksheet's Change event. Here's a simple example that works on column A except the first row

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now()
End Sub
```

The resulting time format can be changed through Format.